# Unable to plot multiple line plots in the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code and I want to draw two lines, both specified in the same data frame. However, I'm getting big coloured shadows, and I'm not able to figure out the cause. The data and the code look correct to me...

```
library('ggplot2')
library('reshape2')

df <- read.csv(url("http://smallchess.com/test.csv"), row.names=1)
melted = melt(df, id.vars='time')
p <- ggplot(data=melted, aes(x=time, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) + geom_line()
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: this plot indicates that you have multiple y values at each unique x value. I suspect that there's a way you can summarize or declare a `group = ...` variable in the `aes()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two variables show extremely oscillating values. So that each line overlaps its neighbor. Thus, this opaque structure is generated. Perhaps it helps if you set your `size` of the line to a low value like this:

```
p <- ggplot(data=melted, aes(x=time, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.05)
print(p)
```

[image]